# Images not displaying on website

Tags: html, web, dreamweaver

The webserver was case sensitive it seems, Thank you very much @David and everyone. Website is working perfectly. :D

So I have had to make a website for a bakery for an assignment but some images are not displaying and I have no idea why e.g. my cookies page is perfect by my cakes page is a disaster (this is my first website so the coding in general is terrible) When I view the website locally the images are displayed perfectly. Hosted by www.000webhost.com. Website was built using Dreamweaver.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.
http://beckasbakery.comlu.com/Cookies.html
http://beckasbakery.comlu.com/Cakes.html

```
COOKIES

#Smartiecookie img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 487px;
    top: 310px;
    width: 208px;
    height: 149px;
}
#Orangecookie img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 486px;
    top: 519px;
    width: 206px;
    height: 145px;
}
#Doublechoccookie img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 210px;
    height: 147px;
    left: 832px;
    top: 314px;
}
#Chocolatecookie img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 838px;
    top: 546px;
    width: 207px;
    height: 148px;
}
</style>



</head>

<body>
<
<div id="Smartiecookie"><img src="Smartie Cookies.jpg" width="364" height="242" /> </div></p></p></p>
<div id="Orangecookie"><img src="Orange cookie.jpg" width="354" height="242" /> </div>
<div id="Doublechoccookie"><img src="doublechoccookie.jpg" width="364" height="242" /> </div>
<div id="Chocolatecookie"><img src="Chocolate cookie.jpg" width="364" height="242" /> </div>

</body>
</html>

CAKES


#Cake1 img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 506px;
    top: 315px;
    width: 208px;
    height: 149px;
}
#Cake2 img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 503px;
    top: 554px;
    width: 206px;
    height: 145px;
}
#Cake3 img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 210px;
    height: 147px;
    left: 904px;
    top: 339px;
}
#Cake4 img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 906px;
    top: 567px;
    width: 207px;
    height: 148px;
}
</style>



</head>

<body>

<div id="Cake1"><img src="Cake 1.jpg" width="364" height="242" /> </div></p></p></p>
<div id="Cake2"><img src="Cake 2.jpg" width="354" height="242" /> </div>
<div id="Cake3"><img src="Cake 3.jpg" width="364" height="242" /> </div>
<div id="Cake4"><img src="Cake 4.jpg" width="364" height="242" /> </div>
```

Comment: The links to live examples aren't working.  And there's *way* too much superfluous code in the question.  Can you reduce the code to a minimal reproduction of the problem?

Comment: are you sure that you have the path to those files for the cakes in the correct position?

Comment: Make sure that the naming of the image files & the paths are correct

Comment: Wow! What's with all the empty ULs?!

Comment: @AndyG Il be honest, I don't know

Comment: I would remove the spaces from all the file names; web locations shouldn't shouldn't contain spaces. In particular `%201` is likely to be mis-interpreted by the browser.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/yaE2XdD.png Picture of all website files, Pics folder only has the background image

Comment: @user2489441: Is the web server case-sensitive?  I don't think it should be, but I suppose anything's possible.  Notice that the HTML code refers to `Cake 1.jpg` but the file listing shows `Cake 1.JPG`.

Comment: @David That is a very good point, checking now

Comment: The webserver was case sensitive it seems, Thank you very much @David and everyone. Website is working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

you have to make sure that you have the image files in the same directory as the .html if you're gonna do it as src="Cake1.png", otherwise, you have to specify the location of the image such as src="img/Cake1.png" or something like that.

Hope that helps

Comment: I know this is just an example, but they are ".jpg" files in the OPs page. Just thought I'd mention to save confusion.

Comment: oh yea, I am used to using png for the compatability....thank you for pointing that out

Comment: No worries, but I'm getting hungry now :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces from the image filenames, "Cake 1.jpg", etc. These are requested as "Cake%201.jpg", where %20 is the space character, but this is likely to be interpreted as %201 (some other character).

Web addresses should not contain spaces, they cause too many problems.

Comment: Done, nothing has changed

Comment: You changed this in both the page and for the uploaded files? The server will probably also take a while to acknowledge the changed filenames.